# Can I add an offer letter (from a previous employer) to my portfolio?

Tags: resume, portfolio

I add a link to my portfolio (on an online drive) on my resume. I worked (as an intern) for a company in the past but, I don't have an experience letter or a recommendation from them. I no longer work for this company. I list this experience on my resume though. *Can I add the offer letter I received from this company to my portfolio (like an endorsement that I did work there as an intern for a specific period)* ? This offer letter includes my hourly wages, bonus etc. I ask because, I don't know if recruiters would think it's weird or non-standard (this is in the US).

There are other things like diploma, transcript, merit certificates and recommendations that I have on my portfolio (in chronological order) already.

Comment: Does this internship you did in the past relate to the jobs you are seeking? What kind of jobs are you seeking and how long ago was that internship?

Comment: @DarkCygnus It was 6 months ago, and I was a 'software development engineer intern' for 3 months. I'm still looking for jobs in this field.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't think you should, it's a private communication between yourself and the company. There are a number of reasons why they wont like you publicising that information. Also this could worry a future employer if they see you have published that type of information about your last company.

If you need/want a recommendation/reference, then email the company and ask if they will provide you with one. Usually it's up to an employer to check your references, you don't usually have to provide proof that your work experience is genuine on a resume.

Comment: Thanks flexi. I did think this through, but the offer letter does not have anything like 'Company Name - confidential' in the header, footer or anywhere in the body.

Comment: If it's up to an employer to check these, let me not add it, as you mentioned.